# How to get number of element in table if it is exist in data base .?

Tags: sql, sqlite, cordova

I need to count number of element in row if it is exist in data base . But query is not running.I am using sqlite in phonegap

```
        db.transaction(function (tx) {

 tx.executeSql('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM b)', [],
   // tx.executeSql('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM  b)', [],
              function(tx, results) {
               t=results.rows.length;
               alert(t)
});
    });
```

Actually i have one table in which i have all tables name .I need to count elements in each  table

```
function getallTableData(tx) {

    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM CaseTable', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}


function querySuccess(){
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    alert(result.rows.item(0).CaseName)
        db.transaction(function (tx) {

 tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM "'+result.rows.item(0).CaseName+'"', [],
   // tx.executeSql('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM  b)', [],
              function(tx, results) {
               t=results.rows.length;
               alert(t)
});
    });

}

}
```

Comment: 1. Which version of cordova are you using? 
2. Are you getting any error or exception?

Comment: What do you mean with "is not running"? Does it not return one row, containing the count value?

Comment: cordova 2.7 .in ios..

Comment: No it not returning any thing..

Comment: can you suggest any method or function which check first table exist in db .If yes then count number of element in table..?

Comment: any idea...to sove this issue